# can I not use the variable inside the loadImage function?

Tags: p5.js

So I want to preload every image inside one folder and to do so I made a loop which makes an address as a variable using a concat() and tries to load the image, but when I put that variable inside the loadImage() I'm getting the error.

I also tried to find the function which would've gotten every file in the folder in array and load images that way, but I couldn't find anything for p5.js

Code works when I do this:

```
  var address = 'ones/one_1.png';
  var img = loadImage(address);
```

Code doesn't work when I do this:

```
  var str = 'ones/one_';
  var n = 1;
  var address = str.concat(n.toString(),'.png');
  var img = loadImage(address);
```

Error:
p5.js says: It looks like there was a problem loading your image.

Comment: No, this issue is not reproducible. Just try `address == 'ones/one_1.png'`, the result is `true`, in both cases. I think this is not the original code, so please provide a [Minimal, **Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm using p5 Web Editor. can that be the problem? because I watched a video where the guy was loading image just by typing loadImage('Image/"+n+".jpg"); which doesn't work for me

Comment: I tried it in a new file and still getting the same problem: function preload(){
  var n = 1;
  var img = loadImage('ones/one_'+n+'.png');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
}

Comment: After that error it should show the path of the image that failed to load. Did you check to make sure the path is correct and that the file exists there?

Comment: Yes the path is correct. Does it work for you in web editor?